# Change default Arabic font on OSX Catalina

Tags: macos, catalina, font, arabic

I'm trying to change the Arabic font on OSX Catalina from the default Geeza Pro to the (system provided) much nicer looking DecoType Naskh.

However I'm unable to disable Geeza, nor make any changes in the /Fonts directory even as root with SIP disabled. There are no other actions on the fonts to say which one is default.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can change system/Library/fonts while booted into another install of macos.

Comment: @TomGewecke like recovery mode ?

Comment: I think you need to boot from a separate partition / volume.  I don't know if recovery mode would work.

Comment: @silkroad Recovery Mode **is** another volume. I tested it and moved DecoTypeNaskh from the ./Fonts/Supplemental to the ./Fonts folder and rebooted. However, after moving to Arabic nothing changed really (I tried to use the ٩ to detect differences because DecoType Naskh's ٩ doesn't really have a (typographic) counter in contrary to Geeza's ٩)